# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined error message in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have the following JavaScript code in my service layer. When this code executes, I get an error saying  - *Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*. I looked at some other similar posts on stackoverflow but still couldn't resolve this issue.

**Question**: What code changes will correct the above error? May be I am calling something in AngularJS the wrong way but not sure.

```
      function getPreferenceSet(type) {
        var t = angular.isString(type) ? type : '';
        logger.info('getPreferenceSet: fetching; type: ' + t);

        var route = userPreferenceConstants.endPoints.PREFERENCE + '?type=' + t;

        var allDashboardsDeferred = false;
        if (!allDashboardsDeferred) {
            allDashboardsDeferred = $http.get(route)
                .then(getPreferenceSetComplete)
                .catch(function (message) {
                    exception.catcher('XHR failed for getPreferenceSet')(message);
                });
        }
        return allDashboardsDeferred.promise;

        function getPreferenceSetComplete(response) {
            logger.info('getPreferenceSet: complete');
            return response.data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you set allDashboardsDeferred it's already set to a promise so I'd guess allDashboardsDeferred.promise is not defined and something above is calling .then on the result. Try updating to `return allDashboardsDeferred;`

Comment: Also the then can take a 2nd function for errors  .then(getCompleteFn,getErrorFn)  and you can log out if you are getting an error.

Comment: @trevor, Yes, all dependencies are injected.

Comment: Do I need to call resolve method somewhere for the promise?

Comment: No, you don't need to call resolve. You're just returning (and chaining) the promise returned from $http.get and that function resolves the promise when the call completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$http.get(route).then(...).catch(...)` is returning an HttpPromise that resolves when the call completes. The allDashboardsDeferred variable is a promise already and not a deferred so you can return it directly:

```
return allDashboardsDeferred;
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know. Thanks.